# What are the type parameters for FileBasedSink?

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm migrating a custom sink extending FileBasedSink from version 2.0.0 to 2.2.0. The class has changed and added two extra type parameters: `UserT` and `DestinationT`:

```
@Experimental(value=FILESYSTEM)
public abstract class FileBasedSink<UserT,DestinationT,OutputT>
extends java.lang.Object
implements java.io.Serializable, HasDisplayData
```

I've checked the doc of [FileBasedSink](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileBasedSink.html) but cannot find the purpose of it.

Of all type parameters only `OutputT` has a documentation:

```
* @param <OutputT> the type of values written to the sink.`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this API is [being redesigned](http://s.apache.org/fileio-write) and will be deprecated in the next version of Beam. However, meanwhile:

- `UserT` is the type of PCollection elements to be written - the `WriteFiles` transform will be applicable to `PCollection<UserT>`.
- `OutputT` is the low-level type of records that will be directly passed to your sink's `Writer`. It differs from `UserT` because some sinks have a "format function", e.g. Avro can convert any record to a `GenericRecord`. `UserT` is mapped to `OutputT` via `DynamicDestinations.formatRecord`.
- `DestinationT` is a logical type for supporting writes to multiple destinations at the same time, e.g. writing events of different type to Avro files with different schemas in different directories. `DestinationT` functions as sort of a grouping key for records to be written, and records with the same `DestinationT` are written using the same configuration. See `FileBasedSink.DynamicDestinations`: `getDestination` extracts the destinations from a `UserT` record, and a bunch of other methods produce the configuration for a given destination, e.g. `DynamicAvroDestinations.getSchema`.

This API is not optimal - e.g. it introduces these high-level concepts (user type and destination) into code specific to file formats (e.g. writing to Avro files). That's why it is being redesigned. Stay tuned for the PR https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/3817 implementing the new API.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. From the API's user perspective it is helpful if it  gets documented even if it's not optimal, because it's what users see.

Would you recommend to keep the version 2.0.0 until the redesign is submitted?